# Post and previous values for an analog input inside a matlab function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I need a Simulink block or a group of blocks to make **peak detection**: compare each value of an input stream to its previous and post values. If it's larger than the previous AND larger than the next value, output this value.

I've tried to do it with a Matlab Function Block, but I cannot make the required delay. I mean it's not possible, as far as I tried, to store previous values for example.

So, what should I do?

***Update: Another example***
In responding to the comments, suggested solutions are helpful if I'm dealing with discrete values. So here is another example to represent my need: 
A Schmidt Trigger
[image]

I need to implement a Matlab function to implement the given scenario. I can do something like

```
if u >= 2
  y = 3;
elseif (u < 2)
  y = -3;
```

But still this is not correct as I need to look at the previous value (hysteresis) of the input, other wise I'll end up having something like the following
[image]

PS: I know there is nothing called previous value in analog, but we all know that Simulink is dealing with analog values as a discrete in the end (much larger sampling). So I think maybe there is a way to do it.

Comment: What about using the [Unit Delay](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html) block twice?

Comment: You would use `persistent` variables within the MATLAB Function block to store the previous values, or alternatively as @MatthiasW has said, you can use a couple of unit delays outside of the block and feed the already delayed signals into the block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using persistent variables or delay is only helpful is I'm using discrete values. For continuous values, it doesn't help. Please check my update above.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is fine except for one minor mistake:

```
if u > 2
y = 3;
elseif u < -2
y = -3;
else
y = u;
```

The variable 'u' in elseif part should get compared with the -2 (upper threshold but with a negative sign)

Hope it helps!